Is saying, "Xylem and phloem are located in the vascular bundle (of root)" wrong?
So basically, this was a question in 2022's NEET paper
Read the following statements about the vascular bundles:
A. In roots, xylem and phloem in a vascular bundle are arranged in an alternate manner along the different radii
B. Conjoint closed vascular bundles do not possess cambium
C. In open vascular bundles, cambium is present in between xylem and phloem
D. The vascular bundles of dicotyledonous stem possess endarch protoxylem
E. In monocotyledonous root, usually there are more than six xylem bundles present
Choose the correct answer from the options given below.
a. A, C, D and E only
b. A, B and D only
c. B, C, D and E only
d. A, B, C and D only
As per the exam conducting body, the correct answer is option 'c', because statement 'A' is wrong. They claim that "Xylem and phloem are located within the vascular bundle" is a more correct statement and not "Xylem and phloem are located in the vascular bundle"

But is it not appropriate to use 'in' in the place of 'within', at least in this context?

I’m voting to close this question because because the function of this site is not to express opinions on the use of prepositions in MCQs.
